# Display a list of shop categories on Big Cartel shop landing

Tags: templates, bigcartel

I'm using the Luna theme of Big Cartel.

My shop sits on **/products** and clicking on a shop category links to **/category/tees** or **/category/accessories** etc.

The **/products** page currently shows a list of *all* products in the store. I want to change that to show a list of categories

Is there a way to check if I'm on a category page or on the shop landing page?

I also tried the following but it doesn't seem to work

```
{% if page.url == '/products' %}
    // Show categories grid
{% else %}
    // Show category products
{% endif %}
```

Any help would be appeciated

Answer (score 0):

Use the `page.full_url` variable with `contains` for best results:

```
{% if page.full_url contains '/category' %}
  // Show category products
{% else %}
  // Show categories grid
{% endif %}
```